# parsing returned HTML by beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some html here and using beautiful soup

At a point I search for a specific div tag as in:

```
print soup.find("div", {"class": "sorteringsvalg Alle"})
```

and the output returned is as follows:

```
<div class="sorteringsvalg Alle"> Alle  <label class="sorteringtype">
<input checked="" name="type" type="radio" value="Alle"/>(638) </label></div>
```

What I am interested in is the number in brackets, so I need to further process this data. I've tried using 're' regular expressions on this but the object returned is not represented as a string so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the inner input and get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "sorteringsvalg Alle"})
print div.find("input", value="Alle").next_sibling.strip()
```

Or, in one go with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("div.Alle input[value=Alle]")[0].next_sibling.strip()
```

Comment: That works great, thank you!
Just a question though, I also discovered that adding .getText() works as well, which would be more efficient of those, do you know?

Comment: @Slavi `get_text()` is also an option but it works on tags only, if you need to locate a "navigablestring" (basically, a text node), then going sideways with  `next_sibling` is good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may get string within  tag as follows:

```
print soup.find("label").get_text(strip=True)
```